# Could not load NIB in Bundle using storyboards and UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an app which is using a UIPageViewController and a sqlite database to populate its content views (data source). After sometime using the app (after turning the UIPageViewController for about 200 times, the app crashes with a Could not load NIB in Bundle. The id of the Object that is trying to load is exactly the content view of the UIPageViewController, which was showing fine in the previous 200 scrolls. Nevertheless, I'm using storyboards, and the view that the compiler is trying to load is in it and works perfectly fine while first using the app for a while. This error is prone to happen whenever I use the app too much. Does anyone know what could it possibly be? I'm using the Simulator (7.1) to run this app.

Comment: its may be memory issue

Comment: You are totally right. I had left some database connections open. Nevertheless, the Leak tool at Instruments would not show this memory issue. Closing all the connections to the database (sqlite3_close) and finalizing (sqlite3_finalize) all the SQL statements solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost 2 days trying to figure out this problem, it turned out to be a memory issue, like BHASKAR pointed.I had left some database connections open. Nevertheless, the Leak tool at Instruments would not show this memory issue. Closing all the connections to the database (sqlite3_close) and finalizing (sqlite3_finalize) all the SQL statements solved the problem.